# Is there a way to get an process exit status after many more commands have been issued in linux?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, exit-status

If I have a lot of commands I've issued and I want the exit status of a process that exited say 100 commands ago. Is there a struct, file location, or variable in linux I can access all of exited processes and see information about them?

Answer (score 3):

If BSD process accounting was enabled (`accton on` was issued), with GNU `acct` 6.6.3 or above, you can get that information from `lastcomm --debug` or `dump-acct /var/log/account/pact` (or wherever the process accounting data is stored on your system).

```
$ perl -e 'exit 123'
$ lastcomm --debug | grep perl
CURRENT REC: perl            |v3|     0.00|     0.00|     0.00|  1000|  1000| 26328.00|     0.00|     332|    8530|     |     123|pts/1   |Wed Sep 19 20:21:26 2018
$ dump-acct /var/log/account/pacct | grep perl
perl            |v3|     0.00|     0.00|     0.00|  1000|  1000| 26328.00|     0.00|     332|    8530|     |     123|pts/1   |Wed Sep 19 20:21:26 2018
```

You get the exit code in the 3rd last field and whether it was killed or not (but not the signal number, see [@mosvy's answer for that](/a/470151)) in the 4th last one.

Answer (score 2):

If you're on debian, you can install the `acct` package in order to enable process accounting, but notice that neither `lastcomm --debug` nor `dump-acct` show anything like the exit status or the signal that terminated a process.

If order to get that data, you can use a script like this:

```
$ cat pacct.pl
#! /usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use Config;
printf "%-7s %6s %6s  %8s %8s  %s\n",
        'STATUS', 'UID', 'PID', 'BTIME', 'ETIME', 'COMMAND';
my @sig = split ' ', $Config{sig_name};
$/ = \64;
while(<>){
        my @f = unpack 'CCSL6fS8A*', $_;
        my ($flag, $version, $tty, $exitcode, $uid, $gid, $pid, $ppid,
                $btime, $etime, $utime, $stime, $mem, $io, $rw,
                $minflt, $majflt, $swaps, $cmd) = @f;
        my $s = $exitcode & 0x7f;
        my $status = $s ?  "SIG$sig[$s]" : $exitcode >> 8;
        printf "%-7s %6d %6d  %02d:%02d:%02d %8.2f  %-16s\n",
                $status, $uid, $pid,
                (localtime $btime)[2,1,0],
                $etime / 100,
                $cmd;
}

# perl pacct.pl /var/log/account/pacct
# tail -f /var/log/account/pacct | perl pacct.pl
```

This assumes the version 3 of the log file format -- see [`acct.h`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/uapi/linux/acct.h).

Notice however that this isn't that useful, because only the process/thread name is included in the log file (ie the basename of the executable, truncated to 15 bytes, and which could be easily faked with `prctl(PR_SET_NAME)`), not the path of the executable or the arguments it was invoked with.

If you want to extend that script to also display the `stime`, `utime`, etc fields, this may be useful:

```
# translate comp_t to float
# utime, stime, mem, minflt, majflt are in the comp_t format
# io, rw, swaps are never set; they're purely decorative
sub comp2f {
        my $m = $_[0] & 0x1fff; my $e = $_[0] >> 13; $m * 8 ** $e;
}
```

**Note:** Instead of installing the `acct` package, you can also turn process accounting on with:

```
# mkdir /var/log/account
# perl -e 'require "syscall.ph"; my $f = shift;
  open my $h, ">>", $f or die "open >>$f: $!" if $f;
  $! = -syscall SYS_acct(), $f // 0 and die "acct $f: $!";
' /var/log/account/pacct
```

Comment: What version of Debian did you try lastcomm --debug/dump-acct on? It worked for me on Debian unstable and on Ubuntu 18.04 (though doesn't give the signal number for those processes that were killed)

Comment: Note that it's not the _command name_, it's the _process name_ (changed by each `execve()` call the process makes to the first 15 bytes of the basename of the executed file). You can't change it with overwriting `argv[0]`, but with `prctl(PR_SET_NAME, newname)` or `execve()`. When you do `env sh -c 'exec bash -c "exit 123"'`, that's one process that runs in turn `env`, `sh` and `bash`. The pacct log will show only one entry for `bash` (the name of the process at the time it exited)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas stretch(stable)

Comment: Yes, you need GNU acct 6.6.3 or above. stretch has 6.6.2.

Answer (score -2):

The

```
  set -o pipefail
```

is pretty close to what you want; it will

> A  pipeline  will not complete until all components of the pipeline have
>    completed, and the return value will be the value of the last non-zero command 
>   to fail or zero if  no  command has failed.

So if you have 40 commands piped together, and the third command gives a return code of 8, and the rest complete successfully, then the overall return code would be 8.  To figure out which command gave the bad return code would be tricky.

Comment: There is no indication that the commands are issued as part of the same pipeline.

Comment: Good point; I didn't read the question closely enough, but I'll leave the answer just in case someone may benefit from it.  It was one of my nice surprises I found when moving from Solaris to Linux.

Comment: Yeah thanks. There's a PIPESTATUS[0] environmental variable as well for pipelines. This would be just in general.